# Adding call out lines for symbols using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, callout

I am making a hiking map and there are usually a few poi’s at one single spot. Let’s say there is a market, atm and a guesthouse at the same spot. I managed to bring these different symbols together on a grid layout using categorized feature. However, since there is limited space on the map, sometimes a call out line is needed.

Is it possible to add call out lines to symbols (I know it’s possible for labels)?